# Can an AC compressor used as a Hydraulic pump?

Tags: hydraulics, hvac

Can a car ac compressor be used as a Hydraulic pump ?
Does it require some modifications to do so or is it impossible to begin with and the compressor can't handle the oil?

Comment: hydraulic systems have to withstand high pressures (imagine the cylinder taking a hard bump) ... so, no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the clearances, compression ratio and valves are not designed for that use.

If you want a hydraulic pump then use a power steering pump, now available in two flavours mechanical ie engine or belt driven and electric.

Answer (score 2):

I would say definitely not. Pumps like that are designed specifically for their application, and changing the working fluid is not what I would call a minor change.
It's possible you could hook it up and get it to run poorly in a fashion, but be prepared for it to break at any moment, so whatever you need the hydraulic pressure for would be at risk. It would be much easier to buy a small hydraulic pump, or better yet a hydraulic jack unless you need a lot of fluid displacement.

Answer (score 2):

- Air compressors work by **compressing** air, a ***gas***.
- Hydraulic pumps work by **pumping** hydraulic fluid, a ***liquid***, which is not compressible.

Attempting to run hydraulic fluid through an air compressor will most likely burst the compressor.